# Do I have to go through immigration and customs and get my bag when there is a layover in Sydney Australia from USA to New Zealand?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, transit, syd

Do we need to go through immigration and customs and collect our bags when flying Delta from the United States, with a 1:15h layover in Sydney, Australia, before flying with Virgin Australia to New Zealand?

Comment: Ask to have your bags checked through to your final destination. They will probably do that as a matter of course, but it is worth confirming it.

Comment: Sydney Airport has quite a decent transit facility.  So long as you listen carefully to the instructions from the flight crew on the way into Sydney, you shouldn't run into any difficulties.  You definitely don't need to go through customs or immigration.

Answer (score 7):

Presuming your fights were booked on a single ticket, you will not need to go through immigration or customs in Sydney.

Your bags will be checked through all the way to New Zealand.

On arrival in Sydney you will need to pass through transit security, which will leave you in the departure area of the International terminal where your Virgin Australia flight will depart from.